# How to print value of a shell variable where the value has double quotes

Tags: bash, shell

Lets say i have a shell variable like the below with the value :-

```html
myvar="abc"xyz
```

Now if i print the value of this variable myvar, the output i get is abcxyz
Is there a way to get the exact output that also includes the quotes. I tried several ways to escape double quotes etc but unable to find a way to do it.

Comment: If that's how the variable is set, it does not have any quotes in it. The quotes affect how the characters between them are parsed, but after they've had their effect on the quoted section, they are removed. As a result, `myvar="abc"xyz`, `myvar="abcxyz"`, `myvar=abcxyz`, and `myvar="a"'b''c'"xyz"` are all fully equivalent, and all store *exactly* the same thing in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html):

```
myvar='"abc"xyz'
```